# Search crawler indexes only top-level site collection

Tags: search, crawling, crawl-rules

We had to redesign and redeploy our web applications, but we didn't want to loose all the data. So we detached all content databases from applications, removed web applications, recreated properly and attached content databaes. It looked very promising, because everything seemed to work properly.

We removed old addresses from content source in search application and added new. After performing full-crawl, we noticed that content of mysite pages and user profiles are indexed properly, but from the second web application there is only content from top-level portal site indexed, and no content from subsites in `/sites` managed path... Search account have `Full Read` permissions on both web applications.

I solved the issue partly by creating new content source and explicitly point to some site collection in `/sites` managed path, but in the long run it is no-go for us because site collections will be created and removed and manual management of content source is out the question.

Could you tell me what possibly might be wrong?

Comment: did you have the content source set to crawl all sites under this start address or just the listed site collections? ref: http://screencast.com/t/spfPh58PgJyN

Comment: I had `crawl everything under the hostname for each start address`. It was default content source, provisioned when setting up search service application.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this error? Thanks in advance